# i keep on getting errors whenever i use if else on my html

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, authentication

We were asked to create a website, I would like to ask if there's something wrong with my form because whenever I open it on my browser it always gets an  error on my html end tag.

---

```
<?php 
 session_start();
 include('connect.php');
 ?>

<?php

  if (isset($_POST['Login'])){

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$login_query=mysql_query("select * from user where username='$username' and     password='$password' and Usertype='admin'") or die(mysql_error());
$login_query1=mysql_query("select * from user where username='$username' and password='$password' and Usertype='user'") or die(mysql_error());



$count=mysql_num_rows($login_query);
$count1=mysql_num_rows($login_query1);

$row=mysql_fetch_array($login_query);
$row1=mysql_fetch_array($login_query1);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystylelogin.css"> 
</head>
<body style="background-color: #66A9EB">
    <header>
        <div class="header"><h1><a href="login.php">Tidbits<a></h1></div>
        <div class="header-cont"> 
    </header>
<form method="POST" action="home.php">
        <fieldset>
                <p> Welcome </p>
                    <br>
                    Username: <input type="text" name="uname">
                    <br><br><br>
                    Password: <input type="password" name="pword">
                    <br>
                <div id="button">
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" style="font-family: Verdana; color: white; font-size: 20px; background-color: #99CCFF; border: 1px solid #3399FF; border-radius:5px; margin-left: 150px" name="do" value="Log In"/>    
                </div>
                <div>
                    <P>

                </div>
            <p id="create"><a href="register.php">Create an Account</a></p>
 <?php 
                        if($count == 1){
                        $_SESSION['id']=$id;
                        header('Location:  admin.php');

                        }
                        if($count1 == 1){
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['id']=$id;
                        header('location:user.php');
                        }

                ?>


        </fieldset>
    </form>
<!----------------------------------SLIDESHOW------------------------------------------------------->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var slideimages = new Array() // create new array to preload images
        slideimages[0] = new Image() // create new instance of image object
        slideimages[0].src = "cookiesandcream.jpg" // set image src property to image path, preloading image in the process
        slideimages[1] = new Image()
        slideimages[1].src = "pizza.jpg"
        slideimages[2] = new Image()
        slideimages[2].src = "waffle.jpg"

        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <img src="cookiesandcream.jpg" id="slide" width="700" height="500" />

        <script type="text/javascript">

        //variable that will increment through the images
        var step=0

        function slideit(){
         //if browser does not support the image object, exit.
         if (!document.images)
          return
         document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src
         if (step<2)
          step++
         else
          step=0
         //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
         setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
        }

        slideit()
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

can you please tell me the error on my codes?

Comment: put semicolon after slideit(); and  setTimeout("slideit()",2500); like this

Comment: What error? Tell us exactly the error that you are seeing and what you expect to see.

Comment: Not knowing what if else has to do with it, or what error you get, I can still say there are errors. You must NEVER use user posted values concatenated in SQL queries! Also header/session_start probably won't work in the middle of the page (unless output caching is on).

Comment: and i don't see the closing of `if(isset){` block.

Comment: where's the closing brace of :  if (isset($_POST['Login'])){

Comment: Your lack of braces and semi-colons in javascript will probably lead to serious bugs. What, do you think, will be returned in this `if` statement: `if (!document.images)`?

Comment: thank you for all of your help its okay now, i think i need to study more about php since im still a beginner

Comment: you should accept @pete's answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

`header` has to be at the top of the page before any output is done (before you start your html)

move this to the to above the doctype tag:

```
if($count == 1){
    $_SESSION['id']=$id;
    header('Location:  admin.php');
}

if($count1 == 1){
    // session_start(); ---------- remove this line as you already started the session at the top of the page
    $_SESSION['id']=$id;
    header('location:user.php');
}
```

[more information about `header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

You have missed you opening `html` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

And you haven't closed the initial `if (isset($_POST['Login'])){` - you need a closing `}`

You also need to remove the following tags from after your initial slideshow script:

```
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: i did forgot about that closing tags and putting semicolon on my slide and on my php i think thats one of the cause of error

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you get a message that your html is invalid? Your starting `<html>` tag is missing.
Correct markup looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Some Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    …
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing curly bracket from the end of the first if statement.

Proper indentation would help immensely in spotting these errors in the future and if you have problems you can't spot try running the code through a php validator, such as http://phpcodechecker.com/

Comment: thanks i did check on my php code with the use of that validator and i saw my errors